# SQL Check if value is beetween two different values from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table like this in my Oracle database

ID
**------**
10 000
25 000
 
40 000
 
61 000
 
75 000

**I need to check if value**, for example 46 567, **is between some of two neighbour values** from this table and **choose the nearest border to value**.

46 567 is between 40 000 and 61 000, I should choose 40 000 because it is closer to 46 567 than 61 000.

Sure I can find top and low borders like this

```
--top border
SELECT MIN(ID) FROM (SELECT * FROM this_table WHERE ID > 46567);
--low border
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM (SELECT * FROM this_table WHERE ID < 46567);
```

But one cool pro told me I should perform some hierarchical query and It will looks really good, I don't see how can I use hierarchical query to solve this problem. It should looks like this Fibonacci SQL, but I can't implement this.

```
WITH
numbers (n, prev) AS (
SELECT 0 n, 1 prev from dual
UNION ALL
SELECT n + prev, n from numbers
WHERE n + prev < 50
)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: You should re-assess the description of "pro" for the person who told you that.  There are much simpler ways to do what you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ... Yeah, I agree, but I won't feel happy until I understand how I can do this with hierarchical query :) Your solution is great, btw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have one number, you can do:

```
select *
from (select t.*
      from likethis t
      where t.id <= 46567
      order by t.id
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

Or, just:

```
select max(id)
from likethis t
where t.id < 46567;
```

EDIT:

If you want the *closest* value:

```
select *
from (select t.*
      from likethis t
      order by abs(t.id - 46567)
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: @suslov . . . That would be a more intelligent interpretation of "is closest to".  Thank you.

Comment: Your solution is absolutely write and nice, but it is not hierarchical query. I am still trying to figure out how to implement 'with', 'connect by prior' and other hierarchical stuff to this, do you see the way to reimplement this solution with some kind of walking through this table with 'with' keyword like in fibonacci example?

Comment: @Raventid . .  . The use of `connect` is entirely unnecessary for this query.  If that is what you want to learn, find another example.

Comment: After playing with this solution I found an important detail I've missed. If we have range 10000 - 30000 and we have value 20000 your query will choose 10000, that is not correct if we round number. So it should be: `order by abs(t.id), t.id DESC`